# Why are the seat belts designed the way they did?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, free-body-diagram

I understand the importance of seat belts in vehicles. Since our body is moving at the same speed as the car, there should be something holding us tight in our seat when we step on the brake.  Most 3-point seat belts designed in almost identical ways but what's the advantage of this shape? and why not any other shape but this?

**Edit:** I would really appreciate it if anyone could show why this 3-point seat belts are widely used instead of other types by showing the free-body diagrams.

Comment: A 5-point system is far superior to a 3-point system, but more expensive.  Further, the "general public" , being very short on brainpower, would react extremely hostily to being required to buckle into a 5-point system.  You may recall the automatic shoulder systems that were required prior to airbag systems being installed, because consumers would refuse even to buckle their 2-point system.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that having a 3-point seat belt as oppose to a 2-point seat belt (across your hips) is that a 3-point would protect both your upper body as well as your lower body from moving in the case of a collision or sudden braking.

There are instances (like race cars) where you would have 4-point (one belt over each shoulder to hips) for motor vehicles that travel at high speeds and a collision may result in injury to the throat or neck region (as may happen for a 3-point seat belt). These, and also the V-shaped four-point seat belt also minimise chest compression by shifting the load from the chest to the pelvis.

There are many other designs but usually for specialist drivers (racing car drivers), and in terms of practicality (when considering driving speeds and other biomechanical factors) and safety, it is probably sufficient to fix all standard vehicles with 3-point seat belts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand what you say, I was actually hoping to see bunch of free-body diagrams to understand why this specific 3-point seat belt is widely used but not others.

Comment: That will take some time. I’ll try to do this for you if I can some time tomorrow. Cheers.

Comment: Oh that would be great, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

This is because the seat belts are designed to make contact with the strongest parts of the human body. In turn, this is because it is supposed to disseminate the force of the collision to the parts of the body most capable of withstanding injury. For adults, this "strongest part" is the torso.

[See e.g.](https://www.everydayhealth.com/healthy-living/wearing-your-seat-belt.aspx)

> "Seat belts prevent occupants of the vehicle from serious injury in five ways," says Angela Osterhuber, director of the Pennsylvania Traffic Injury Prevention Project in Media, Pa. A seat belt:
>
> ...
>
> **Restrains the strongest parts of the body**. "Restraints are designed to contact your body at its strongest parts. For an older child and adult, these parts are the hips and shoulders, which is where the seat belt should be strapped," Osterhuber says.
>
> **Spreads out any force from the collision**. "Lap-and-shoulder belts spread the force of the crash over a wide area of the body. By putting less stress on any one area, they can help you avoid serious injury," Osterhuber says. A shoulder strap also helps keep your head and upper body away from the dashboard, steering wheel, and other hard interior parts of the automobile should you stop suddenly or be hit by another vehicle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any link or source where I can actually see how the forces affect on human body if different types of seat belts are sued?

Answer (score 1):

The main advantages of the three point restraints used in most modern vehicles are ease of use with only one buckling point, and some freedom of movement when the upper attachment reels in and out. And It is a reasonably safe and comfortable way to hold the lap and torso in the seat. Many race and competition vehicles have a four point harness and a head and neck support (HANS). This is generally safer and more secure than just the three point restraint but it takes longer to get in and out of. The two point lap belts used in some older cars are not nearly as safe because the torso could be thrown around more in accidents or emergency stops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time, I'd appreciate it if there are some simulations showing how different type of seat belts affect the forces exerted on different parts of  human body.

Comment: Here are a number of vids that may be of interest;https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=seat+belt+simulation